# Removing dynamically added event handlers with .off()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add event handlers via:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.name', function(e)
```

These `.name` elements are dynamically added.

I can't seem to remove the event handler via:

```
$('.name').off('click');
```

Do I need to pass `.off()` via `document` to make this work?

Comment: *Do I need to pass .off() via document to make this work?* Well, have you tried? What happened?

Comment: It didn't remove the handlers. Not with `$('.name').off('click');`

Comment: _"I add event handler**s** via"_ - There's only one event handler and that one is attached to the document.

Comment: You can use `$(document).off('click', '.name');` (credit to @Yuri's comment on my now deleted answer).

Comment: $( document ).off( 'click', '.name')